# Get a components location on its current monitor

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu, multiple-monitors

I want to set the location of a `JPopupMenu` depending of the y location of the button that opens the menu. My code works fine on my first monitor, but fails on my second monitor, wich has a different height. 
The problem is `getLocationOnScreen()` delivers the location relative to the main screen, not the actual screen on which the component is shown.

My code:

```
// screenSize represents the size of the screen where the button is
// currently showing
final Rectangle screenSize = dateButton.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();

final int yScreen = screenSize.height;
int preferredY;

// getLocationOnScreen does always give the relative position to the main screen
if (getLocationOnScreen().y + dateButton.getHeight() + datePopup.getPreferredSize().height > yScreen) {
  preferredY = -datePopup.getPreferredSize().height;
} else {
  preferredY = getPreferredSize().height;
}

datePopup.show(DateSpinner.this, 0, preferredY);
```

How can I get the location of a component on its actual monitor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a solution for this using the bounds of the second screen, it's quite simple:

```
public static Point getLocationOnCurrentScreen(final Component c) {
  final Point relativeLocation = c.getLocationOnScreen();

  final Rectangle currentScreenBounds = c.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();

  relativeLocation.x -= currentScreenBounds.x;
  relativeLocation.y -= currentScreenBounds.y;

  return relativeLocation;
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What if the secondary monitor is a the opposite site? What if the primary and secondary monitors get changed?

Comment: shouldn't it be "+=" ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you call "getLocationOnScreen()" it gets the location of the component "this" (from the code I don't quite understand who "this" is).

Maybe you can try to get location of the button by using "button.getLocationOnScreen()".

Comment: This is called inside of a panel that contains the button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet that shows how to position elements relatively to another one. It displays a popup menu below the button, and a JDialog to its left. I tested it on a multi-screen environment where secondary screen is on the right of the main one.

Also, use getSize(), getWidth() and getHeight() instead of getPreferredSize(). getSize(), getWidth and getHeight return the actual dimensions of the component, while getPreferredSize() is only an indicator to the LayoutManager to what the component wishes to have.

If you use the method `JPopupMenu.show()` make sure to use coordinates and sizes relative to the invoker component.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Some test"));
                System.err.println(button.getLocationOnScreen());
                popupMenu.show(button, 0, button.getHeight());
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
                dialog.setSize(100, 30);
                Point locationOnScreen = button.getLocationOnScreen();
                locationOnScreen.x += button.getWidth();
                dialog.setLocation(locationOnScreen);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                info(button);
            }

            private void info(final JButton button) {
                if (button.isShowing()) {
                    System.err.println(button.getLocationOnScreen());
                    System.err.println(button.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                info(button);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

            }
        });
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```